# How docker swarm kill unhealthy containers

Tags: docker-swarm, kill

Docker swarm does have a health check options since [`API 1.25+`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/)

I'm looking for a way to update docker swarm services without affect service availability.

A simple solution would be just set the health check to a unhealthy state and wait for docker swarm update with the new image version, but I'm afraid it can kill containers with current active threads.

Since I haven't found a way to disable incoming requests for specific containers I wonder what is the kill signal sent to container.

If a `15)SIGTERM`, there is a `9)SIGKILL` after some timeout ? and what is the timeout ? There is a way to customize it?